# Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.2.0/gradle-3.2.0.pom'

Tags: android, android-studio

I update my android studio to 3.2 and then I created new project but it have error:
[image]
My computer haven't proxy but I can try add

```js
# Gradle settings configured through the IDE will override
# any settings specified in this file.
# For more details on how to configure your build environment visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html
# Specifies the JVM arguments used for the daemon process.
# The setting is particularly useful for tweaking memory settings.
# Default value: -Xmx10248m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
# org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
# When configured, Gradle will run in incubating parallel mode.
# This option should only be used with decoupled projects. More details, visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:decoupled_projects
# org.gradle.parallel=true
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m
systemProp.https.proxyHost=192.168.100.11
systemProp.https.proxyPort=8080
systemProp.http.proxyHost=192.168.100.11
systemProp.http.proxyPort=8080
baseApiUrl="http\://"
```

to `gradle.properties` and it not working. so I revert it to default ( only `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m`)
How I can fix it?